# Display data with odds and evens

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've checked around google and in here and I am unable to find an answer specific to what I'm wanting to do.

Basically, I am trying to make a table with the database like this:

```
[0001][0002]
[0003][0004]
```

However, for some reason I am unable to do that.

This is what I've got down, and it's not even functioning. I would like to note that I am pretty new to php, although that may be obvious.

```
<table>

<?php

...

$x = 0;

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
    while($info['id'] <= 4)
    {

        if($x ==0){       // [I feel like the error is in here.]
            Print "<tr>";
            $x++;
        }elseif($x == 2){
            Print "</tr>";
        }else(){
            $x++;
        }

        Print '<td><a href="'.$info['url'] . '"><img src="' .$info['img'] . '" width="210" height="157"></a>';
        Print "".$info['name'] . "</td>";
    }
}
?>

</table>
```

Without the counter, the table is more of a single-column table going down.

Comment: what error type you have

Comment: two tds will be easier :-)

Comment: It doesn't tell me any errors. It's just a blank-page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few issues:

- Syntax errors in your print lines, your concatenation (.) areas have inconsistencies with the type of quotes you're using to get back into the string e.g. ' or "
- Identifying which column and where the break point is isn't really there

Try something like this (assume your database results are fine):

```
<table>
<?php
// ...
$i = 1;
$columns = 2;

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
    if($i == 1) {
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    echo '<td><a href="'.$info['url'].'"><img src="'.$info['img']. '" width="210" height="157">' . $info['name'] . '</a></td>';

    if($i == $columns) {
        echo '</tr>';
        $i = 1;
    } else {
        $i++;
    }

}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: This..fixed it perfectly. 

I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also: When it comes to my quotes that I use, it's problematic for that? Or is it just bad/weird code-ethic? I'd prefer mine to be legible, so I am going to work on fixing my issues up with that.

Comment: No worries. Quotes: it doesn't really matter which you use. If you use single quotes, you don't need to add slashes to double quotes, if you use double quotes, you don't need to add slashes to single quotes, and PHP variables will parse without breaking up the string (although I don't like doing that, better to break the string). I find using single quotes is better when outputting HTML as you don't need to worry about the double quotes for tags. Consistency would suggest using one or the other but not normally both... Also, double quotes will parse things like \n but singles wont